# How do I install Windows on a virtual hard disk (VHD) from within a running Windows system?

Tags: windows-7, installation, vhd, windows-installation

If you just try to attach a VHD and then install Windows to a partition inside it, it will tell you that it's a "surfaced virtual disk" and that Windows cannot be installed to that partition.

But obviously it's a lie, because this is possible when booting directly off a DVD. :-)

So how do you do that from a running system?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, **a warning**: *Close all your programs and save all your files before attempting this!*  Make sure there is nothing important still in the system cache! ([Sync](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897438.aspx) is handy for this.)

Windows does **NOT** perform a "graceful" shutdown using this trick!

When you're done with that, to 'trick' the installer thinking it's in Windows PE, simply create the registry entry

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\MiniNT

and run the installer from the DVD. It will now allow you to install to a VHD.

Once the installer says "Restarting in 10 seconds...", press Alt-Tab to go back to the registry editor (have it open!) and *delete* the MiniNT key so that you don't trick any *other* programs into thinking your current system is a PE system. :)

Now the system will reboot the kernel (the user mode shutdown process is bypassed) and should continue installing Windows to your partition.

Note 1: Drive letters probably won't be preserved this way, though.

Note 2: You can "try" to attempt to "fix" the drive letters immediately on the first reboot, before the second, when the installation is about to perform system-specific configurations. **If you do so**, however, be warned: Your `\Users\All Users` junction (and all the tens of other junctions/symbolic links) will point to your **old** system drive, not the new one! So you have to be prepared to fix this manually -- and yes, it's a pain to do this 'correctly' without corruption.

Comment: You could, in theory also edit the registry offline i suppose, or create a script that adds and removes the registry entry . *Really* cool trick tho

Comment: Some of the negative side effects of `MiniNT` are described [here](https://www.quppa.net/blog/2016/04/14/beware-of-the-minint-registry-key/).

Comment: Installation media created using recent `MediaCreationTool.exe` no longer let me skip the warning about installing Windows on VHDX. Running setup using this trick issues same warning, but it can be skipped! This is now my favorite [way to install Windows on VHDX](https://superuser.com/a/1262653/238468).

Answer (score 0):

Performing an install of Windows to a partition inside of a VHD, while running Windows consists of a few steps and some specific tools.

Tools required:

1. ImageX - specifically for the platform of your current installation of Windows (i.e. x64 or x86). You can get it as part of the Windows Automated Installation Kit here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5753.
2. DiskPart - built into Windows 7.

High level steps:

1. Using DiskPart, create the VHD. Then mount it in Windows, partition it, and assign a drive letter to the partition you'll want to use for the new installation. For discussion, let's say you assign the drive letter as "Z:\".
2. Get access to the Windows 7 "install.wim" file. You can find it in the "\sources" directory of the Windows 7 installation disc. For discussion, let's say you have that mounted/inserted into drive letter "D:\".
3. Using ImageX from an Administrator command-line, apply the Windows 7 "install.wim" file to the new VHD's partition by using the following command:

   imagex.exe /apply D:\sources\install.wim 1 Z:\

You can find more info about the ImageX tool here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749447%28v=ws.10%29.aspx.

I hope that helps. I have used the above technique to make fresh installs of Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008/2008 R2 for both virtual machines and "boot from VHD" scenarios.