# What are the ways to install Windows on VHDX

Tags: windows, vhdx

What installation options do I have when I want to native boot from VHDX?

Answer (score 0):

## 1 Traditional

**1.1 Standard installation from external media**

- the installation media is created using [Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)

  - requires DVD or USB flash drive
- you follow the installation as normal and when it comes to selecting disk you need to press `shift+F10` to open command line and use `diskpart` to create and mount your vhdx

  - you can then select the virtual drive for installation
- the setup will warn you that the disk can't be used for installation but the warning can be skipped and ignored

  - the warning can no longer be skipped when you use installation media created from [Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) downloaded after Windows 10 Falls update (cca Oct 2017)

    - the warnings include: `the selected disk is not the computer's boot disk`
    - `the selected disk space is not of type esp`
    - `the selected disk is a surfaced virtual disk`
    - you may want to try **1.2** below

**1.2 Standard installation from Explorer**

- the installation media is created using [Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)

  - requires DVD, USB flash drive or ISO
- you can run the `setup.exe` from installation media directly from Windows if you trick it to think it is run from [WindowsPE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Preinstallation_Environment)

  - there is really simple temporary registry hack using [MiniNT](https://superuser.com/a/435108/238468) key for this
- standard installation follows then
- the difference with **1.1** is that now:

  - you can use GUI tools instead of `diskpart`
  - some warnings preventing installation to VHDX that could not be ignored before can be skipped now!

---

## 2 Imaging

**2.1 [ImageX](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722145(v=ws.10).aspx)**

**2.2 [DISM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism---deployment-image-servicing-and-management-technical-reference-for-windows)**

- deprecated [ImageX](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722145(v=ws.10).aspx)

**2.3 [Convert-WindowsImage.ps1](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Convert-WindowsImageps1-0fe23a8f)**

---

## 3 Conversion

**3.1 [Disk2VHD](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/disk2vhd) from Sysinternals**

- this small tool can snapshot online Windows system into VHDX file that is bootable
- uses [Volume Shadow Copy Service](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee923636(v=ws.10).aspx) to preserve consistency of the snapshot

Answer (score -1):

Easy way to install windows on vhdx - without changing registry and bypassing issue with "disk can't be used for installation" :

1. create the installation usb using Media Creation Tool
2. start installation from usb, go until the screen with disk choice (on which to instal). In the process write down which consecutive number has the version of windows you want to install (there will be a list), don't enter windows key, you will do it later
3. press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>
4. use `diskpart` to create vhdx, attach it, create partition, format and assign letter (example V).
5. use command: `Dism /Apply-Image /ImageFile:F:\sources\install.wim /index:1 /ApplyDir:V:\`
   where
   `F:\sources\install.wim` points to the USB (can be whatever, not necessary `F:` and it can be also `install.esd` file there)
   index:1 - I have taken first windows from the list (windows 64 home), put the number you noted in point 2
   `V` - the letter assigned to vhdx in point 4
6. after the installation is finished, type `exit`, remove usb and restart computer
7. if you have more systems on your disk - add the new vhdx to bootlog